# Laravel-Lighthouse scopes are not updated

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, lighthouse, laravel-lighthouse

I have a query on Lighthouse which is using `@paginate` scope with another 3 scopes

This is my query

```
profiles(where: _ @whereConditions(columns: ["email"])): [User!]! @paginate(scopes: ["byOrganizationLoggedIn","byMatchingRole", "byAvailableMatching"]) @middleware(checks: ["auth:api"])
```

And those are my scopes from User entity.

```
   /**
     * @param [type] $query
     */
    public function scopeByOrganizationLoggedIn($query)
    {
        if ($organization = request()->user()->organization_id) {
            $query->where('organization_id', $organization);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param [type] $query
     */
    public function scopeByMatchingRole(Builder $query)
    {
        if (request()->user()) {
            $query->whereHas('roles', function ($q) {
                $q->whereIn('name', ['Mentor', 'Mentee']);
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param [type] $query
     */
    public function scopeByAvailableMatching(Builder $query)
    {
        if (request()->user()) {
            $query->whereDoesntHave('matchedProfiles', function (Builder $q) {
                $q->where('user_id', request()->user()->id);
            });
        }
    }
```

The problem is that my last scope `byAvailableMatching` is not called and if I remove one of the other scopes `byOrganizationLoggedIn` or `byMatchingRole` it's still going into the entity methods.

I've tried to reset the lighthouse cache using

```
php artisan lighthouse:clear-cache
```

But the query and the scopes are not updated and they are returning the same data.

I'm new to Laravel and Lighthouse and if you have any suggestions to filter the query by all the scopes let me know.

Comment: How did you test that it did not call the scopes and it's simply your scopes not working correctly?